# EnumerateFiles with subdirectories in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I am trying Mono on a linux ubuntu.
Enumartion of Files wont work with subdirectories. If i use GetFiles() it will work.
I used a console to get the output of the files so I wont get the enumerat output:

```
   [Test]
        public void NotImportentTest ()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("test");
                        Directory.CreateDirectory("test/dings");
            File.Create("test/dings/hallo").Close();
            var curdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var searchdir = new DirectoryInfo(curdir + "/test");
            var files = searchdir.EnumerateFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enumerate:{0} in {1}\r\n", file, curdir);
            }
            foreach (var file in searchdir.GetFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GetFiles:{0} in {1}\r\n", file, curdir);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please specify "won't work". What happens exactly? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: oh sorry, no File is listed. So it wont jump in the foreach loop where I use Enumerate. the GetFiles loop will show the file.

Comment: Works fine here with mono 2.11.4.

Comment: did u run it under a Linux?